# PHPMailer- Should I send emails in runtime, or via cron job?

Tags: php

I am using the PHPMailer library to handle the sending of emails from within my application.

The problem is, when some emails are triggered to be sent (such as when a contact form has been submitted, a new user registers, etc), it could take 1-3 seconds for the page to load while the email is sending. If there is ever a problem sending the mail, the delay can be more.

I was thinking of saving any emails that need to be sent into a `pending_emails` table in my database, then just have a cron job ran every minute which would send out all those emails, then remove them from the table.

My question is, does this seem like a logical thing to do? Are there any potential resource concerns I should have with a cron job running every minute vs sending the email in runtime? (I need to run the cron job often, as someone may be waiting on an urgent message, for example "reset password" email)

Comment: alternate to options above create a mail script you can call from the command line then run `exec('script >pipe output ot stop blocking');` your main script will continue instantly but its not so great for error handling. I call it a poor-mans  multi-\threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very opinion based question so you're going to get a lot of different, conflicting answers because there are some who might tell you its ok to make a user wait 1-3 seconds since its not that long but I tend to disagree with that. What I typically do instead, however, is use a `Queue`.

[There are ways to create a queue WITHOUT using 3rd party software](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/creating-a-message-queue-in-php), but there are some excellent tools out there such as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html), [Iron.io](https://www.iron.io/platform/ironmq/) or [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) which can be extremely helpful to performing tasks in the background. These services push your task into a queue and these items in the queue are processed in a timely manner in the **background**, but the user gets an almost immediate response (depending on what you're doing). This is how I usually handle more resource intensive tasks, like sending an email, in the background to avoid holding up the response to a user.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You got everything right already.

Sending at runtime, just when you respond to the user's HTTP request, is the easiest thing to do. But the response is slowed down a bit by this, of course. That's not *too* bad in a small application, because sending email is faster than one might think. It definitely works.

Implementing a message queue is the more elegant and scalable approach, of course. But it takes a little more work. Your idea of using a `pending_emails` database table is totally valid. There are libraries and components for such queues, but you don't have to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Look into threading ([PHP Threading](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)). I would suggest you create a new thread which invokes the sending of the email. This way, you can return a response to the user without waiting for the email to be sent, and the email sending process would run in parallel in another thread.